# MAILTO just opening blank chrome page

Tags: html

My idea is that i let user fill in text-boxes, and then i want him to press send button, and that text would be sent to my e-mail. But every time, when i press the send button, opens a new, blank chrome page, no matter from which browser i work...
Here is the part of the code, that operates with it. Hope u cann help to solve my issue.

```
<form action="MAILTO:example@domain.lv" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="tekstaievadei">Name:</span></td>
                    <td><input id="vards" type="text" name="name"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="tekstaievadei">Surname:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="tekstaievadei">Nr:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nr" id="nr"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
             </form>
```

Comment: To my knowledge, you will need some server-side code (ex: PHP) to get that mail sent. What your code does is typical of browsers and was meant to be that way. In short, it will not do what you want done.

Comment: See this question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pre-populate an email with the values of form fields. Using `mailto` simply opens a new email to the given email address. Send the email from the server side if you want full control.