# How to send information submitted in html to email

Tags: html, forms

I am making a website and I want one of the pages to have a form where they write their contact information and then have it sent to me when they press the submit button. I tried doing it in HTML by using this code

```
<form action="MAILTO:XXXXX@XXX.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

And then I have the form entries and a submit button. I enter some random details but it never sends me an email.

Here's my form entries if it means anything

```
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

Comment: The client needs email set up properly.

Comment: You'll need a server side language to send an email .... only HTML can do nothing about this.... or you need to use an external service where you use their API to send an email via their service..

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html

Comment: `mailto` asks the browser to send an email. It needs to know the email program outlook/thunderbird ets. If that has not been configured the form will fail

Comment: @EdHeal who is talking about `mailto:` ? He wants to send an email via HTML which is not possible..

Comment: ... format action bit is "mailto:..."

Comment: @EdHeal I think he is mixing up the anchor tag `mailto:` with the `action` attribute

Comment: @Mr.Alien - We are second guessing the action. A mailto action is valid

Comment: Here is already replied similar question 
[How to send an email using PHP?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Answer (score 0):

As others stated in comments above, you're mixing up 2 things. You have 2 options going forward.

1. Option 1 is using a server-side language like PHP to send the e-mail. This is a bit harder to do, but it allows you to have a form on your page like you describe in your question. In this case, you'd have to change the action attribute of the `<form>` to the path to the (PHP) page/file that will process the POST request. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm) on how to send e-mail in PHP.
2. Option 2 is to get rid of the form and replace it with a link that will boot the user to his e-mail program with the `To:` field already filled out. Obviously, this will only work if the user has a local e-mail program set up. It's usually not compatible with webmail (like Gmail, Outlook.com...). However, it can be implemented in a single line of code:

Should you opt for option 2, you can just replace the `<form>` element with the following code snippet, which will produce the link:

```
<a href="mailto:your-address@example.com">your-address@example.com</a>
```

Note that in the snippet above, I repeated the e-mail address as the text of the `<a>` tag. This ensures that people who use webmail can copy-paste the e-mail address in the web app.