# How send HTML responsive e-mail?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm new to html and css. Earlier I made responsive e-mail using `Ink framework`. Now I want to send this e-mail but I don't know how.

I don't want to use `Mailchimp` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I actually use ASP C# to send my emails now, with something that looks like :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
    {
        string formEmail = "";
        string fromEmail = "from@email.com";
        string defaultEmail = "default@email.com";

        string sendTo1 = "";

        int x = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            formEmail += "<strong>" + Request.Form.Keys[i] + "</strong>";
            formEmail += ": " + Request.Form[i] + "<br/>";
            if (Request.Form.Keys[i] == "Email")
            {
                if (Request.Form[i].ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    fromEmail = Request.Form[i].ToString();
                }
                formEmail += "<br/>";
            }

        }
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage myMsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        try
        {
            myMsg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(defaultEmail));
            myMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            myMsg.Body = formEmail;
            myMsg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromEmail);
            myMsg.Subject = "Sent using Gmail Smtp";
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("testing@gmail.com", "pward");

            smtpClient.Send(defaultEmail, sendTo1, "Sent using gmail smpt", formEmail);

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            debug.Text += ee.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example using gmail as the smtp mail sender. Some of what is in here isn't needed, but it is how I use it, as I am sure there are more effective ways in the same fashion.

Or see the demo pages

[DEmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html)

[Demo1](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/email-form-mailto.html)