# How to create custom form in blogger sending to admin email?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, blogger

I want this code form is actually work and emailing to admin email of blog.
I don't have any idea, to make it real.

```
<form id="partner" action="" method="post" name="contact-form" enctype="text/plain">
    <h3><span>Daftar Partner</span></h3>
    <label>Name Fansub</label>
    <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="A3Substream" size="20" />
    <label>Website</label>
    <input type="text" name="alamat" placeholder="http://www.a3substream.net" size="20" />
    <label>Link Banner</label>
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="imagelink" size="20" />
    <button id="ContactForm1_contact-form-submit" type="button">Kirim sekarang!</button>
    <button type="reset" value="Batal">Batal</button>
    <div style="max-width: 222px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
        <div id="ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message">
        </div>
        <div id="ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)

Comment: Also relevant: [How to create an email form that can send email using html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html)

Comment: Alot of tutorials out there, first try them, and when you try one and it does not work, then come and some one will help you from there, after you have tried something.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend with the server you are working with. Some will accept the simple example provided below. Adding the PHP code for sending the mail

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['nama']) && ((isset($_POST['nama']) != ""))) {
$nameofsender = $_POST['nama'];
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$message = $_POST['mail'];
$body ='<html>
<body>
<div class="content">
<p style="text-align:center;">'.$message.'<p><br />
</div>
</body>';

$headers='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: MY BLOG <info@myblog.com>' . "\r\n";
$subject = "$nameofsender - Message from blog";
//mail function
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if(!$mail) {   
     echo "Error sending email";   
} 
else {
    echo "Your email was sent successfully.";
}
}
?>

YOUR FORM......
```

Some servers are strict more so windows based servers and may require more detail before sending mails like the code below

```
/*email starts*/    
require_once "http://www.yourblog.com/Mail.php";

$from = "Your blog <info@yourblog.com>";
$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$to = "<$email>";
$subject = "$nameofsender - Message from blog";
$message = $_POST['mail'];
$body = $body ='<html>
<body>
<div class="content">
<p style="text-align:center;">'.$message.'<p><br />
</div>
</body>';

$host = "mail.yourwebsite.com";
$username = "info@yourwebsite.com";
$password = "passwordtousernameabove";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);


$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => 25,
    'auth' => true,

    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
YOUR FORM....
```

For better understanding google for tutorials on this topic as it is a shot but wide interesting topic. Regards

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not including my blog information, but i used blogger and you know that blogger don't support php, so if you pleasure please give me another way like javascript or another that support in blogger.

Comment: it has to support php. saving your files with an extension of. php . it is not about blogger. its about server. but this is the best solution i could give.

Comment: so i cant just add function from blogger using id or javascript, to be honest using php is really complicated, but really thank you.

Comment: if your file is saved as e.g. index.html. change it to index.php simple. then add the code above just on top of your <form….  try the first one. just do a little modification. php is not hard