# HTML send answers to email

Tags: html

the problem is I don't know anything about HTML, but I do have template which I need to edit. 
I want answers of those textboxes(how should I call them?) to be sent to directly to my email, but how should I do this???
[image: the problem]

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: you need php or something similar to do this, please provide code of your html and add the php tag. - for more info read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete and without of any code which you have tried , but what i have understand with the incomplete information is that you want to send the information from a form fields to your mail...for this you would need php , javascript etc for your form to send the information from your page to the mail...
I will prefer you the folllowing link to visit for this.
http://htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/