# Send emails with form in HTML

Tags: html

I am starting in the Web development and I would like to know how to send HTML forms to the email that is selected, already indicated me PHPMailer but I searched knew and did not understand very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an email form that can send email using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to send form information to an email address? If so you probably don't need something like phpMailer but rather just include a mailto: action in the form tag. ([example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail))
It really depends on what exactly you're trying to do the form data you're collecting.

Comment: Thats it , im trying to send form information to email. How to use mailto? Send example in a code pls.

Comment: click on the example link and it will bring you to an interactive page that had a good demonstration of mailto:

Comment: thank you :D solved

Comment: no problem! Happy to help!