# How to create a email form that can send mails in wagtail

Tags: php, html-email, wagtail

I want to implement an email form in my wagtail project using HTML. Searched around and found this:
[How to create an email form that can send email using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html)
Does anyone have any experience of how to implement PHP in a wagtail project?

Comment: Wagtail is based on Python and the Django framework. PHP is a totally different programming language, so "implementing PHP in Wagtail" is not a meaningful concept. The answers on the other question saying to use PHP are aimed at someone who has not yet chosen a platform for their server-side code. Since you've chosen Wagtail, Django and Python as your platform, that's what you need to build your form in. See https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any way to implement a form inside a block and send the form to a specific email? What I want is a "sign up for the newsletter" module, what I found so far in the docs is just how to make a separate form site.