# How to make this contact form work open the mail client on mobiles?

Tags: android, html, forms, html-email

```
    <form action='mailto:myemail@email.com?subject=wazzup' enctype='text/plain' method='post'>
<input name='Name' placeholder='Name' size='50' type='text'/><br/><br/>
<input name='Email' placeholder='Email' size='50' type='text'/><br/><br/>
<textarea cols='49' name='Comment' placeholder='Your message' rows='4'/><br/><br/>
<input style='background:#000;color:silver;' type='submit' value='SEND'/><br/><br/>
</form>
```

Shouldn't this work on mobile devices as well as desktop? On desktop it opens the email client, just as it should. Why not on mobile?
I'm trying it on Android 10/Chrome, and it does not open the Gmail client that I use, nor the Yahoo app.
I've also tried enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and method='get'.

Comment: I have never seen it done this way - however if you are doing it this way,wouldn't you be better offoverriding the form submit in javascript or jquery, and bulding the proper link using that (e.g. mailto:myemail@email.com?subject=wazzup&body=data)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an email form that can send email using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239782/how-to-create-an-email-form-that-can-send-email-using-html)